# Heat Energy $\propto 1/R$ or $\propto R$?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I know that heat energy can be calculated by $I^2 R t$. Therefore, it's directly proportional to resistance.

However,

$$I^2  R  t = \frac{V^2}{R}t$$

In this case, won't the heat energy be inversely proportional to the resistance? Won't these 2 statements contradict each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implicitly assuming that $I$ and $V$ are *constant* quantities.  If one says that $x$ is proportional to $y$, it means $x = ay$ where $a$ is a constant.

But consider what happens when you change $R$: either $V$ or $I$, or both, change.  They are not constant.

I think it would be better to say that power is proportional to $I^2$, with coefficient of proportionality $R$, and power is also proportional to $V^2$, with coefficient of proportionality $1/R$.
Changing $I$ or $V$ does not affect the value of $R$ (not in simple analyses anyway).